# Polymorphic in Silverstripe CMS

Tags: polymorphism, content-management-system, backend, silverstripe

I use a [polymorphic relationship](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/relations/#polymorphic-has-one) in my SilverStripe project. Now I want to add in the CMS a button to add a new polymorphic object.

It would be fine, if it will be a step by step progress. First step get a dropdown with all Object with a link to the main object.

Step two create the object of step one.

Comment: Can you please share some example code? We can't help you otherwise